# JavaScript Invalid export data. Please provide an array of objects

Tags: javascript, c#

Im writing a function to export data pulled from C# to a csv file in JavaScript. The data is trying to be passed into an active webpage with live data. The goal is to export said data from C# string to the clients window hence the transfer to JavaScript (if my understanding is right). Then the JavaScript function in the page will download to the users window.

My issue is why am I have the invalid export data, please provide an array of objects output when I think I provide it one?

C# Code:

```
protected string test()
{
    MyRequest request = new MyRequest();
    request.Id = "TEST";
    // Cant post this class but this is what I do
    var tmp = new ExistingClassOfMine();
    // pulls the data from the existing class through GetResponse();
    // Then convert to json string
    string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tmp.GetResponse(request));
    // Data found from breakpoint: {"Slot1":[{"Name":"TJ", "ID":"123"},{"Name":"Joe","ID:456"}], "TotalCount":2}
    return data;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function exportToExcel() {
    console.log("Exporting to Excel");
    isExporting = true;
    const fileName = 'NameList';
    const exportType =  'csv';
    var data = <%=this.test()%>;
    var readData = data["Slot1"];
    var myArray = [];

    // Followed a stack article to create this
    for (var i in readData) {
        myArray.push(readData[i]);
    }
    // Logging stuff for debugging
    console.log("Data from C#");
    console.log(data);
    console.log(typeof (data));
    console.log("Data we want to export");
    console.log(readData);
    console.log("Parsed Data?");
    console.log(myArray);

    // fails here with the error Invalid export data, please provide an array of objects
    // which I thought I did with my for loop up a few lines
    window.exportFromJSON({myArray, fileName, exportType});
    isExporting = false;
}

function onRequestStart(sender, args) {
    if (isExporting) {
        args.set_enableAjax(false);
    }
}
```

Log output:
[image]

Comment: The documentation shows data in the form of objects in an array, with each object being a key-value pair. eg. `var data = [ { item1 : 'Item 1' }, { item2 : 'Item 2' } ]`.  From docs: `If the exportType is 'json', data can be any parsable JSON. If the exportType is 'csv' or 'xls', data can only be an array of parsable JSON. If the exportType is 'txt', 'css', 'html', the data must be a string type.`

Answer (score -1):

Look, your triying to change the name of the key which is sent to exportFromJSON. The right way to name the key is data no myArray.
Change:
myArray
to
data
or assign myArray to data key
window.exportFromJSON({**data:myArray**, fileName, exportType});